# Salt state to change permissions on a single existing file

Tags: salt-stack

I know this is probably something super easy that I am just overlooking. For the life of me, I don't see an existing salt state that one can use to simply change the permissions on an already existing file. There's a file.managed state that can be used to "create" a file based on source but what if you just want to insure the permissions on a file that is not created through salt has the correct permission and update them if not.

For example, I can create a state like the following:

```
base security tcpd host-allows:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/hosts.allow
    - create: False
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
```

However, when I apply this state, I get a warning:

```
[WARNING ] State for file: /etc/hosts.allow - Neither 'source' nor 'contents' nor 'contents_pillar' nor 'contents_grains' was defined, yet 'replace' was set to 'True'. As there is no source to replace the file with, 'replace' has been set to 'False' to avoid reading the file unnecessarily.
```

Is there a better way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `file.managed` is used to modify file content but it also has a `replace` argument which can be used to change only permissions and ownership.

See https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed

> replace
> : True
>
> If set to False and the file already exists, the file will not be modified even if changes would otherwise be made. Permissions and ownership will still be enforced, however.